# "ConnectionError: Already connecting to database! Call close before connecting to different database" connecting SQL server with nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2012, npm, protractor, mssql-jdbc

Below is the code i am using ,Some times it does not enter .then (function() ,Please let me know how to close the existing connection , I have tried various options like conn.close() after connecting, but it still dint work.

```
var sql = require("C:/Protractor_Scripts/node_modules/mssql");

function getEmp() {
    console.log('results'); 
    var conn = new sql.Connection("Server=, 1433;Database=;User Id=;Password=;Encrypt=true");
    console.log(conn); 
    console.log(conn.connect());
    conn.connect().then(function () { 
        console.log(conn.connect()); 
        var req = new sql.Request(conn); 
        req.query("select * from").then(function (recordset) {
            console.log(recordset);   
            conn.close();
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);   
            conn.close();
        }); 
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);  
    });
}

getEmp();
```

Below is the full error message

[ConnectionError: Already connecting to database! Call close before connecting to different database.]

```
  name: 'ConnectionError',
```

message: 'Already connecting to database! Call close before connecting to
different database.',

```
  code: 'EALREADYCONNECTING' }
```

Comment: Hey got any solution on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing multiple conn.connect() calls and have only one call.

Comment: Code has only one conn.connect() call.

Comment: There are 2 conn.connect() calls within console.logs, those count as connections too.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at their docs, I would try something like:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var connection = new sql.Connection({ /* config */ });

connection.request().query('select * from mytable').then(function(recordset) {
    console.dir(recordset);
    connection.close();
});
```